# Getting compilation error iterating a HashMap in JAVA

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, apple-m1

**Iterate a HashMap**

I am trying to execute the following code in visual studio code on my M1 Macbook Air machine. But getting these errors. Although the code executes in online IDE.

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --enable-preview -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -cp "/Users/shoumik/Library/Application Support/Code/User/workspaceStorage/c7518cbb3ce46c96e642c654a9524389/redhat.java/jdt_ws/jdt.ls-java-project/bin" Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
The method entrySet() from the type Map<String,Integer> refers to the missing type Set

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Entity;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        hm.put("abc", 123);
        hm.put("def",321);
        hm.put("ghi",33);

        
        Iterator<Entry<String,Integer>> hmIterator = hm.entrySet().iterator();

        while(hmIterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String,Integer> entries = hmIterator.next();
            System.out.println("Key is" + entries.getKey());
            System.out.println("Value is " + entries.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The code compiles correctly for me using OpenJDK compilers.  There is probably something broken with your VSC installation, or configuration or something.

Comment: There exist awesome IDEs for java development, for example IntelliJ IDEA; why would anyone be using VSCode for that?

Comment: I'm using Win10, OpenJDK11.0.8, installed extension: Java Extension Pack. After organizing imports or removing unused imports, `import java.util.Set;  import javax.swing.text.html.parser.Entity;` was gone. and the code worked well on my machine. Is there any difference after you clean the java workspace and rebuild the project? or try to import these packages again except unused ones?

Comment: I cleaned the java workspace and rebuilt the project. weirdly enough, it worked. Though still confused Anyways, Thanks @MollyWang

Comment: @Shoumik. You're welcome. the official docs says: In some rare cases, you may need to clean the Java workspace by executing the Java: Clean the java language server workspace command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) to let the language server rebuild your dependencies. Whatever, glad your question had been solved.